# Build a matrix starting from instances of structure fields in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix, data-structures, data-science

I'm really sorry to bother so I hope it is not a silly or repetitive question.
I have been scraping a website, saving the results as a collection in MongoDB, exporting it as a JSON file and importing it in MATLAB.
At the end of the story I obtained a `struct` object organised 
[like this one in the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iAoYb.png).

What I'm interested in are the two last cell arrays (which can be easily converted to string arrays with `string()`). The first cell array is a collection of **keys** (think unique products) and the second cell array is a collection of **values** (think prices), like a dictionary. Each field is an instance of possible values for a set of this keys (think daily prices). My goal is to build a **matrix** made like this:

```
KEYS   VALUES_OF_FIELD_1   VALUES_OF_FIELD2   ...   VALUES_OF_FIELDn
A             x                   x                        x
B             x                   z                       NaN
C             z                   x                        y
D            NaN                  y                        x
E             y                   x                        z
```

The main problem is that, as shown in the image and as I tried to explain in the example matrix, I don't always have a value for all the keys in every field (as you can see sometimes they are 321, other times 319 or 320 or 317) and so the key is missing from the first array. In that case I should fill the missing value with a NaN. The keys can be ordered alphabetically and are all unique.

What would you think would be the best and most scalable way to approach this problem in MATLAB?

Thank you very much for your time, I hope I explained myself clearly.

EDIT:
Both arrays are made of strings in my case, so types are not a problem (I've modified the example). The main problem is that, since the keys vary in each field, firstly I have to find all the (unique) keys in the structure, to build the rows, and then for each column (field) I have to fill the values putting NaN where the key is missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now, I've solved it by considering the longest array of keys in the structure as the complete set of keys, let's call it `keys_set`.

Then I've created for each field in the structure a Map object in this way:

```
for i=1:length(structure)
    structure(i).myMap = containers.Map(structure(i).key_field, structure(i).value_field);
end
```

Then I've built my matrix (`M`) by checking every map against the `keys_set` array:

```
for i=1:length(keys_set)
    for j=1:length(structure)
       if isKey(structure(j).myMap,char(keys_set(i)))
           M(i,j) = string(structure(j).myMap(char(keys_set(i))));
       else
           M(i,j) = string('MISSING');
       end
    end
end
```

This works, but it would be ideal to also be able to check that `keys_set` is really complete.

EDIT: I've solved my problem by [using this function](https://it.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24834-union-of-several-arrays) and building the correct set of all the possible keys:

```
%% Finding the maximum number of keys in all the fields
maxnk = length(structure(1).key_field);
for i=2:length(structure)
    if length(structure(i).key_field) > maxnk
        maxnk = length(structure(i).key_field);
    end
end

%% Initialiting the matrix containing all the possibile set of keys
keys_set=string(zeros(maxnk,length(structure)));

%% Filling the matrix by putting "0" if the dimension is smaller
for i=1:length(structure)
    d = length(string(structure(i).key_field));
    if  d == maxnk
        keys_set(:,i) = string(structure(i).key_field);
    else
        clear tmp
        tmp = [string(structure(i).key_field); string(zeros(maxnk-d,1))];
        keys_set(:,i) = tmp;
    end
end

%% Merging without duplication and removing the "0" element
keys_set = union_several(keys_set);
keys_set = keys_set(keys_set ~= string(0));
```

Comment: Is there any definite way to determine the keys? suppose the keys must be lies within A to Z, or is it just random? And whats your procedure to determine the keys_set?

Comment: The keys are like items leaving or entering a catalogue, so in a certain instance we hay have them and in another we may not. For now I just take the largest array of keys (supposing without proof that the other are all subarrays of this one) and use it as `keys_set`. But as you said the best way would be check all the keys arrays and merge them without duplicates, but for now I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Thank you, I've find a community function making the union of more than 2 arrays, I've edited my answer with the correct solution. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to remember you can't simply use both strings and number in one matrix. So, if you combine them together they can be either all strings or all numbers. I think all strings will work for you.

Before make a matrix make sure that all the cells have same element.

```
new_matrix = horzcat(keys,values1,...valuesn);
```

This will provide a matrix for each row (according to your image). Now you can use a for loop to get matrices for all the rows.

Comment: I forgot to specify that in my case both are arrays of strings, so this is not a problem. The main problem is that I have a variable array of keys and firstly I have to find all the possible keys in the structure, to build the rows. Then I have to fill the matrix putting NaNs in the case that in that column (field) a particular key is not present.

Comment: So, you have to find all the available keys in there and then merge them together? So far, what you have tried? Can you add the code?

Comment: Yes finding and merging all the keys is the main issue. I'll post my partial solution as answer. Thank you for your interest.